# Get product price and description by store wise in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to get product price and description for different stores in magento, I can achieve this as follows:-

```
foreach ($productObj->getStoreIds() as $_storeId) {
                $tempStoreObj = new Mage_Core_Model_Store();
                $tempStoreObj->load($_storeId);

                $tempProductObj = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
                $tempProductObj->setStoreId($_storeId);
                $tempProductObj->load($productObj->getId());


                $tempPriceArray[] = array(
                    'websiteId' => $tempStoreObj->getWebsiteId(),
                    'price' => $tempProductObj->getPrice(),
                    'baseCurrency' => $tempStoreObj->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
                );
                $tempDescArray[]=array(
                'descprition' => $tempProductObj->getData('description'),
                'shortDescription' => $tempProductObj->getData('short_description'),
                );

            }
```

Now In the above code there, I have first fetched stores for particular product, then loaded the stores then again created an object for product and loaded w.r.t **product id** and  **store id** , in this way i have achieved the required task.

Now my problems start here when there are many products and many stores performance issue comes in and the loading process makes this slow.

Is there any other way achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to speed things up when you want to get this from several products is to use the product collection, so there is only one DB query which fetches the information per store for all products.

This would then look something like this:

```
$storeId = 1; // Current Store you want to look at
$productIds = array(10,15,26); // Enter your Ids
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products   = $product->getCollection()
              ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
              ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
              ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
              ->addAttributeToSelect('description');
```

And then loop over the products:

```
$currPrices = array();
foreach ($products as $prod) {
   $currPrices[$prod->getId()] = $prod->getPrice();
}
```

To make it clear for several stores:

```
$currPrices = array();
$currDescriptions = array();
foreach ($productObj->getStoreIds() as $_storeId) {
    $productIds = array(10,15,26); // Enter your Ids
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $products   = $product->getCollection()
                  ->addStoreFilter($_storeId)
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('description');

    foreach ($products as $prod) {
       $currPrices[$_storeId][$prod->getId()] = $prod->getPrice();
       $currDescriptions[$_storeId][$prod->getId()] = $prod->getDescription();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but I need all available prices for different stores.i.e if there are three stores i need all three prices in different stores, therefore i cannot filter w.r.t store_id in my collection

Comment: @chanz Well, you can do three times the collection, so you have 3 queries, instead of doing one query for each product times each store, that was my suggestion :)

Comment: @chanz For clarification, added the multi store way

Answer (score -2):

The fastest way is to make direct queries (of course, wrapped to Zend_Db_Select) to store and product tables.

base_currency can be got from core_config_data

product prices can be found in catalog_category_product_index

description in catalog_product_entity_text

Look to

```
Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Index_Abstract
Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Product_Viewed_Collection
Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Product_Viewed
Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection
```

Magento uses Zend_Db_Select, even fetch methods of the adapter, not collections, in case of increasing speed of queries.

Comment: Manipulating data via direct SQL scripts is always a bad idea when you have a good ORM system with CRUD provided (which is the case with Magento).

Comment: Are yu realy sure? ;) If performance is the goal, nothing will be faster then SQL queries. Yes, it is needed to wrap them, for example, to Zend_Db_Select objects or to use PDO, but this will work really faster then Magento loads and collections. Just for example -- try to load 10 000 Magento items. If you are not trust this -- look to Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Product_Viewed_Collection as example. Why Magento uses $adapter->select() (Zend_Db_Select) but not its colections? ;) Performance is the answer.